# DISTINCT and ORDER BY in the same command without using the order by variable

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, distinct

I need to select the recent 5 games the user has gone into but I don't want there to be duplicates. So I need a SQL line that will take them in order from most recent to least but also make sure there are no distinct. To order them I have a time variable, but if I use:

```
select distinct name, image, time 
from history 
where userID = USERID 
order by time desc
```

this removes all the other times apart from the first ones meaning that I will get the result in the order of which game was played first ever.

If you still don't understand here is the schema and some of the data I have:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE history (userID integer, name text not null, image text not null, time text not null);
```

Data:

```
6 | Arcade Mathematicians | arcadeMathematicians | 2021-04-17 07:59:00  
6 | Arcade Mathematicians | arcadeMathematicians | 2021-04-17 08:01:04  
6 | Infinite Spinner | infiniteSpinner | 2021-04-17 08:01:08  
6 | Arcade Mathematicians | arcadeMathematicians | 2021-04-17 08:01:12  
6 | Arcade Mathematicians | arcadeMathematicians | 2021-04-17 08:02:13  
6 | Infinite Spinner | infiniteSpinner | 2021-04-17 08:02:16  
6 | Arcade Mathematicians | arcadeMathematicians | 2021-04-17 08:03:16  
6 | Infinite Spinner | infiniteSpinner | 2021-04-17 08:03:18  
6 | Arcade Mathematicians | arcadeMathematicians | 2021-04-17 08:03:21
```

So if you see here if I use distinct on time it won't work, as everything would still be displayed.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Your description involves something called a "game" but there is no such entity or column in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rank each row of the table based on user and game and ordered by time descending.
From these results keep only the rows with rank = 1, meaning the latest rows for each combination of user and game.
Then use `ROW_NUMBER()` again to rank the remaining rows based on user and ordered by time descending and from the results keep only the rows with rank <= 5:

```
WITH 
  cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, name ORDER BY time DESC) rn1
    FROM history
  ),
  cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time DESC) rn2
    FROM cte1
    WHERE rn1 = 1
  )
SELECT userid, name, image, time 
FROM cte2
WHERE rn2 <= 5
```

If you want results for a specific user it is easier, just use MAX() window function and sort the results to get the top 5 rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, name, image, 
       MAX(time) OVER (PARTITION BY name) time 
FROM history
WHERE userid = 6
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5
```

Or if the image may be different for the same name form row to row:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, name, 
       FIRST_VALUE(image) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time DESC) image, 
       MAX(time) OVER (PARTITION BY name) time 
FROM history
WHERE userid = 6
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af9a8618b86979e6b9cf02313e4a28d3).
Results (for your sample data):

> | userid | name | image | time |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 6 | Arcade Mathematicians | arcadeMathematicians | 2021-04-17 08:03:21 |
> | 6 | Infinite Spinner | infiniteSpinner | 2021-04-17 08:03:18 |

Comment: Ah okay I will try that out as soon as possible, thanks!

Comment: I dont really under stand the ROW_NUMBER() could you explain it please @forpas?

Comment: @infinity_ninja1239 you can read about it her: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

Comment: Hi @forpas your suggestion was great and it worked but the only problem, which was partly my fault, was that it only gave me the recent games for everybody as the data I gave you was the 6th users history but it is an easy fix so thank you!

Comment: @infinity_ninja1239 see my edited answer for a simpler solution if you want results for 1 user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific user that you want and you want the most recent five rows for that user where name/image are unique, you can use aggregation:

```
select h.name, h.image, max(h.time)
from history h
where h.userID = ?    -- ? is the user you want 
group by h.name, h.image
order by max(h.time) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support the standard `fetch first` clause.  Some use `limit`, `select top` or other constructs.

Comment: Yes, I do want it from a specific user but I want them all to be distinct and in answer to your 2nd question this a history table where the users game history is recorded so that it will be displayed to them on an HTML page. The image column is so that it can display the image, the name column to display the name, and the time so that we can order it by time and get the most recent games they have played. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @infinity_ninja1239 . . . Then I think this answers your question.